# Problems drawing in OpenGL ES 2D Orthographic (Ortho) mode

Tags: android, opengl-es

I've been beating my head against the desk trying to figure this out for days now, and after scouring Stack Overflow and the web, I haven't found any examples that have worked for me. I've finally got code that's seems close, so maybe you guys (and gals?) can help me figure this out.

My first problem is that I'm trying to implement a motion blur by taking a screen grab as a texture, then drawing the texture over the next frame with transparency -- or use more frames for more blur. (If anyone's interested, this is the guide I followed: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/openGL/MotionBlur.aspx)

I've got the screen saving as a texture working fine. The issue I'm having is drawing in Ortho mode on top of the screen. After much head banging, I finally got a basic square drawing, but my lack of OpenGL ES understanding and an easy to follow example are holding me back now. I need to take the texture I saved, and draw it into the square I drew.  Nothing I've been doing seems to work.

Also, my second problem, is drawing more complex 3d models into Ortho mode. I can't seem to get any models to draw. I'm using the (slightly customized) min3d framework (http://code.google.com/p/min3d/), and I'm trying to draw Object3d's in Ortho mode just like I draw them in Perspective mode. As I understand it, they should draw the same, they should just not have depth. Yet I don't seem to see them at all.

Here's the code I'm working with. I've tried a ton of different things and this is the closest I've gotten (actually drawing something on the screen that can be seen). I still have no idea how to get a proper 3d model drawing in the ortho view. I'm sure I'm doing something horribly wrong and probably completely misunderstanding some basic aspects of OpenGL drawing. Let me know if there's any other code I need to post.

```
// Gets called once, before all drawing occurs
//
private void reset()
{
    // Reset TextureManager
    Shared.textureManager().reset();

    // Do OpenGL settings which we are using as defaults, or which we will not be changing on-draw

    // Explicit depth settings
    _gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);                                   
    _gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    _gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LESS);                                      
    _gl.glDepthRangef(0,1f);                                            
    _gl.glDepthMask(true);                                              

    // Alpha enabled
    _gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);                                        
    _gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);    

    // "Transparency is best implemented using glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA) 
    // with primitives sorted from farthest to nearest."

    // Texture
    _gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST); // (OpenGL default is GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP)
    _gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR); // (is OpenGL default)

    // CCW frontfaces only, by default
    _gl.glFrontFace(GL10.GL_CCW);
    _gl.glCullFace(GL10.GL_BACK);
    _gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);

    // Disable lights by default
    for (int i = GL10.GL_LIGHT0; i < GL10.GL_LIGHT0 + NUM_GLLIGHTS; i++) {
        _gl.glDisable(i);
    }

    //
    // Scene object init only happens here, when we get GL for the first time
    // 
}

// Called every frame
//
protected void drawScene()
{   
    if(_scene.fogEnabled() == true) {
        _gl.glFogf(GL10.GL_FOG_MODE, _scene.fogType().glValue());
        _gl.glFogf(GL10.GL_FOG_START, _scene.fogNear());
        _gl.glFogf(GL10.GL_FOG_END, _scene.fogFar());
        _gl.glFogfv(GL10.GL_FOG_COLOR, _scene.fogColor().toFloatBuffer() );
        _gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_FOG);
    } else {
        _gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_FOG);
    }

    // Sync all of the object drawing so that updates in the mover
    // thread can be synced if necessary
    synchronized(Renderer.SYNC)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _scene.children().size(); i++)
        {
            Object3d o = _scene.children().get(i);
            if(o.animationEnabled())
            {
                ((AnimationObject3d)o).update();
            }
            drawObject(o);
        }
    }

    //
    //
    //
    // Draw the blur

    // Set Up An Ortho View
    _switchToOrtho();

    _drawMotionBlur();

    // Switch back to the previous view
    _switchToPerspective();

    _saveScreenToTexture("blur", 512);
}

private void _switchToOrtho()
{
    // Set Up An Ortho View
    _gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    _gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); // Select Projection
    _gl.glPushMatrix(); // Push The Matrix
    _gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Matrix
    _gl.glOrthof(0f, 480f, 0f, 800f, -1f, 1f);
    //_gl.glOrthof(0f, 480f, 0f, 800f, -100f, 100f);
    _gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); // Select Modelview Matrix
    _gl.glPushMatrix(); // Push The Matrix
    _gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Matrix
}

private void _switchToPerspective()
{
    // Switch back to the previous view
    _gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    _gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    _gl.glPopMatrix();
    _gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    _gl.glPopMatrix(); // Pop The Matrix
}

private void _saveScreenToTexture(String $textureId, int $size)
{
    // Save the screen as a texture
    _gl.glViewport(0, 0, $size, $size);
    _gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureManager.getGlTextureId($textureId));
    _gl.glCopyTexImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL10.GL_RGB,0,0,512,512,0);
    _gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    _gl.glTexParameterx(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
    _gl.glViewport(0, 0, 480, 800);
}

private void _drawMotionBlur()
{
    // Vertices
    float squareVertices[] = {
        -3f, 0f,     // Bottom Left
        475f, 0f,     // Bottom Right
        475f, 800f, // Top Right
        -3f, 800f  // Top Left
    };

    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareVertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(squareVertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    //
    //
    // Textures
    FloatBuffer textureBuffer;  // buffer holding the texture coordinates
    float texture[] = {         
            // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
            0.0f, 1.0f,     // top left     (V2)
            0.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom left  (V1)
            1.0f, 1.0f,     // top right    (V4)
            1.0f, 0.0f      // bottom right (V3)
    };
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareVertices.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(texture);
    textureBuffer.position(0);
    //
    //
    //

    _gl.glLineWidth(3.0f);
    _gl.glTranslatef(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    _gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    _gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    _gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
    //_gl.glTranslatef(100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //_gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);
    //_gl.glTranslatef(100.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    //_gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);


    _gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    _gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    _gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    _gl.glLoadIdentity();

    //
    //
    //
    _gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureManager.getGlTextureId("blur"));
    _gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
    _gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    //
    //
    //

    _gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    _gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    _gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
}
```

---

**EDIT:** Here's a simpler example, it's all in the one function and doesn't include any of the saving the screen to a texture stuff. This is just drawing a 3d scene, switching to Ortho, drawing a square with a texture, then switching back to perspective.

```
// Called every frame
//
protected void drawScene()
{   
    // Draw the 3d models in perspective mode
    // This part works (uses min3d) and draws a 3d scene
    //
    for (int i = 0; i < _scene.children().size(); i++)
    {
        Object3d o = _scene.children().get(i);
        if(o.animationEnabled())
        {
            ((AnimationObject3d)o).update();
        }
        drawObject(o);
    }

    // Set Up The Ortho View to draw a square with a texture
    // over the 3d scene
    //
    _gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    _gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION); // Select Projection
    _gl.glPushMatrix(); // Push The Matrix
    _gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Matrix
    _gl.glOrthof(0f, 480f, 0f, 800f, -1f, 1f);
    _gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW); // Select Modelview Matrix
    _gl.glPushMatrix(); // Push The Matrix
    _gl.glLoadIdentity(); // Reset The Matrix


    // Draw A Square With A Texture
    // (Assume that the texture "blur" is already created properly --
    // it is as I can use it when drawing my 3d scene if I apply it
    // to one of the min3d objects)
    //
    float squareVertices[] = {
        -3f, 0f,     // Bottom Left
        475f, 0f,     // Bottom Right
        475f, 800f, // Top Right
        -3f, 800f  // Top Left
    };

    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareVertices.length * 4);
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    FloatBuffer vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(squareVertices);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);

    FloatBuffer textureBuffer;  // buffer holding the texture coordinates
    float texture[] = {         
            // Mapping coordinates for the vertices
            0.0f, 1.0f,     // top left     (V2)
            0.0f, 0.0f,     // bottom left  (V1)
            1.0f, 1.0f,     // top right    (V4)
            1.0f, 0.0f      // bottom right (V3)
    };
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(squareVertices.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(texture.length * 4);
    byteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    textureBuffer = byteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
    textureBuffer.put(texture);
    textureBuffer.position(0);

    _gl.glLineWidth(3.0f);
    _gl.glTranslatef(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    _gl.glVertexPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
    _gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    _gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, 4);

    _gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    _gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    _gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
    _gl.glLoadIdentity();

    _gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, _textureManager.getGlTextureId("blur"));
    _gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, textureBuffer);
    _gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    _gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
    _gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    _gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    // Switch Back To The Perspective Mode
    //
    _gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    _gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
    _gl.glPopMatrix();
    _gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
    _gl.glPopMatrix(); // Pop The Matrix
}
```

---

**EDIT2:** Thanks to Christian's answer, I removed the second `glVertexPointer` and `_gl.glBlendFunc (GL10.GL_ONE, GL10.GL_ONE);` (I deleted them from the sample code above as well so it wouldn't confuse the question). I now have a texture rendering, but only in one of the triangles that make up the square. So I'm seeing a triangle in the left portion of the screen that has the texture applied. Why is it not being applied to both halves of the square? I think it's because I have only one of these calls: `gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);` so I'm literally only drawing one triangle.

Comment: If you're having problems with orthogonal projection, do you have any easier to read code examples? All these motion blur related methods are very confusing here. It was easier to try helping if you could provide a bit more shorter code example focusing on orthogonal projection and it's usage.

Comment: Added a simpler version of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you set the blend function to (GL_ONE, GL_ONE), which will just add the blur texture to the framebuffer and make the whole scene overbright. You probalby want to use (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA), but then you have to make sure your blur texture has the correct alpha, by configuring the texture environment to use a constant value for the alpha (instead of the texture's) or use GL_MODULATE with a (1,1,1,0.5) coloured square. Alternatively use a fragment shader.

Second, you specify a size 3 in the second call to glVertexPointer, but your data are 2d vectors (the first call is right).

glOrtho is not neccessarily 2D, its just a camera without perspective distortion (farther objects don't get smaller). The parameters to glOrtho specify your screen plane size in view coordinates. Thus if your scene covers the world in the unit cube, an ortho of 480x800 is just too large (this is no problem if you draw other objects than in perspective, as your square or UI elements, but when you want to draw your same 3d objects the scales have to match). Another thing is that in ortho the near and far distances still matter, everything that falls out is clipped away. So if your camera is at (0,0,0) and you view along -z with a glOrtho of (0,480,0,800,-1,1), you will only see those objects that intersect the (0,0,-1)-(480,800,1)-box.

So keep in mind, that glOrtho and glFrustum (or gluPerspective) all define a 3d viewing volume. In ortho its a box and in frustum its, guess a frustum (capped pyramid). consult some more introductory texts on transformations and viewing if this was not clear enough.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It was actually already set to (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA), I think that (GL_ONE, GL_ONE) got pasted in with some other sample code I was trying out last night. I'll get rid of that.  I had set the ortho mode to be 480x800 because that was the size of the screen. As you're explaining it, I should use much smaller coordinates and the texture will still display correctly?  Also, I understand Ortho is not 2d, I meant that I'm trying to display something 2d in ortho mode (a square). My second task is to display 3d objects in ortho mode as well.

Comment: I'll try changing those coordinates as you suggested, and I'll remove the second glVertexPointer call, but my big problem is getting the texture to render. I can see the box, so that's working, I just can't get the texture to display.

Comment: @einsteinx2 for your square the chosen ortho is just perfect and it is common to set the ortho to the screen size, when rendering ui-stuff or such things, it just doesn't work for your normal 3d objects (as to the second part of your question). Another appraoch is to use ortho (0,1,0,1) and draw a unit square (so your screen size can be changed and is not written to the square coordinates), but then you have to adjust the translation (which is not in pixels anymore). Just keep in mind. that your square verts and translation (for the blur) have to match the ortho.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like I'll need to change to that approach because I want to not only draw a full screen square for the motion blur (which will only be applied sometimes), but I want certain HUD features like little 3d models of spinning hearts for example for the life counter.

Comment: Also, I took out that second glVertexPointer and it looks that got me part of the way there, can you see what I'm missing that's causing only one triangle to be drawn? Also, and this is just a hole in my understanding of OpenGL, when two triangles are drawn, how does it know to apply the texture over both, and not a separate copy of the texture on each one? Thanks for all the help!

Comment: how the texture is applied is specified by the texture coordinates. It uses these coordinates per pixel (which are the values of the vertices interpolated over the triangle) to get the colour from the texture. I just saw, that your texture coordinates are messed up, they should be {0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1}, to match your vertices, as in OpenGL the screen origin and the texture origin are both in the lower left corner.

Comment: I also saw, that your vertex order is wrong. Your triangle strip renders a triangle with the first three verts and a second one with the last three. With your vertices you get the triangle in the lower right corner and then a triangle in the upper rigth, which is flipped and thus culled away by the backface culling. In this example you could just change the primitive type from GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP to GL_TRIANGLE_FAN. Or you can change the vertex ordering to {0,0, 1,0, 0,1, 1,1} and also for the texCoords, but then your line loop won't work, so the triangle fan is a good solution.

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!! It's working great now, after I switched the vertex coordinates and switched the glOrthof call to `_gl.glOrthof(0f, 1f, 0f, 1f, -1f, 1f);` as you suggested.